# Internet Explorer not returning AJAX call while Chrome is

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm testing an application in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer right now. I have a an AJAX call to a PHP script that returns data from a database, which is then appended to a $('#div') element via JavaScript ... the code functions correctly in Chrome (which is why I don't think it's a code issue) (it takes a second or two to load) ... in IE, however, it's not working (the $('#div') element isn't loading the returned JSON data (like it does in Chrome, albeit it takes a second or two)) ... I've researched other threads and have tried to troubleshoot a potential timeout issue ... any ideas to help troubleshoot?

Comment: did you check if your Jquery works with EI? try alert("IN") in your main javascript to see if Jquery is identified properly.

Comment: Something functions in Chrome but not Internet Explorer?! Welcome to the world of web-dev (trust me though, it's nowhere near as bad as it was 15 years ago) ... you'll have to post some code, there's a reasonable chance it **is** a code issue but not what you think it is - it could well be IE doing something differently to Chrome (or everything else including sanity).

Comment: The first place to look is browser developer tools, network tab, and examine the requests/responses.

Comment: found the issue ... in IE, a date object from jQuery datepicker is returning "NaN" instead of the a value (like it is in Chrome) (which is instructing the query) ... troubleshooting now ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. JS tends to block code from running, whenever there is another JS error on the page. Check IE's equivalent of console.log, to make sure that you don't see any more JS errors either in your code or from some upstream script provider... like a 3rd party ad vendor.

Also, IE doesn't like certain things, which Chrome, Firefox, Safari & Opera will allow... like a trailing comma at the end of the JSON object, before the closing brace "}". That will break in IE, but not in other browsers, which are more forgiving. Example: The comma after apples will break in IE. So look for any trailing commas & remove them.

```
{
   "a": 123,
   "b": "Hello World",
   "c": "apples",
}
```

Try using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect the network traffic, which goes over the wire from IE. It's like Chrome's Network tab & it will show you if the Ajax request is being sent & if so, what's coming back from the Ajax call. You might find an error in that callback & additional clues, as to what's blocking IE from working.

Comment: found the issue ... in IE, a date object from jQuery datepicker is returning "NaN" instead of the a value (like it is in Chrome) (which is instructing the query) ... troubleshooting now ...